# Java: null safe compareTo method

Tags: java, compare, comparator

It has been asked before, but I have not found a decent implementation with an explanation.

```
public int compareTo(Object o)
{
    if (this == null || o == null)
    { 
        return 0;
    }
    Tok tmp = (Tok) o;      
    if (this.rang < tmp.rang)
    {
        return -1;
    } else if (this.rang > tmp.rang ) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I read two similar questions that I found yet; they insist on implementing another method. I do not understand why this should not work. The method gets an extra object and it checks if its a valid instance or `null`, if `null` simply return `0`; what would be the easiest way to implement null-safe `compareTo`.

The implementation that worked for me was:

```
public int compareTo(Object o)
{
    if (o == null)
    { 
        return 0;
    }
    Tok tmp = (Tok) o;      
    if (this.rang < tmp.rang)
    {
        return -1;
    } else if (this.rang > tmp.rang ) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

It's not the optimal implementation one should look in to what good people posted here as answers. For my particular case this was decent enough as this is never null yet the object received can be null and the initial implementation states if either is null return 0. So if given object is null 0 is returned.

Comment: `this` is **never** `null` in Java.

Comment: @MattBall he probably meant **this.someInstance**

Comment: This code would see the null object as equal to anything else. May not be the most consistent way of sorting.

Comment: This is probably a typo but your method return 0 every time o is null. This is not good for an compareTo method

Comment: You don't need to "innovate" in compareTo, aka reinvent the wheel. If you use an IDE it will probably do it for you letting you choose the variables you want to use. Otherwise consider using Guava's ComparisonChain. If you are happy with your own implementation, however, I would get rid of those elses for a neater code.

Comment: this should be compareTo(Tok o), no cast

Comment: Do NOT check for null! the compareTo contract demands that its must throw a NullPointerExceptiopn if you call  x.compareTo(null). See my answer below. Further see docu of object.comparTo.

Comment: Update: I implemented an Comparator, see below, and first did (nearly) the same you have done in your first line (this == null || other == null). But this failed. It give me the wrong order; Later I realized that this cannot work. See below my update on (Becaue the author is insisting ..)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Personally, I like [Guava's `Ordering`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html) for null-safe comparing. You can specify [`#nullsFirst()`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html#nullsFirst%28%29) or [`#nullsLast()`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html#nullsLast%28%29) to avoid `NullPointerException`s.

Other important notes, mostly from the comments:

- `this` is **never** `null` in Java
- Consider using [Guava's `ComparisonChain`](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CommonObjectUtilitiesExplained#comparecompareto) if you're implementing a fine-grained `compareTo()`
- When implementing [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html), be sure to specify the type parameter so you get compile-time type safety and don't have to use `instanceof` or casts:

  ```
  class Tok implements Comparable<Tok> {
      // snip

      public int compareTo(Tok other) {
          // snip
      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 5):

Returning 0 would imply that `this` and `o` are equal, which isn't true if `o` is null. Also, `this` will never be null.

It's application-dependent, of course. You may want to have an object that should be equal to null. What you return there is up to you, but if you're looking for a general null safe method, it isn't really ideal.

To be completely generic, I would check if `o` is `null` and, if so, throw some sort of Exception.

Comment: Specifically a NullPointerException according to Comparable's documentation. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html

Comment: I dont need exception i have an array of Tok[] objects i give it to Arrays.sort() and i get Null exception.

Comment: Emmerioch is right, trust us, do not Null check, see my answer below, but make your code clean, be removing or avoiding null objects in your Tok[] you want to sort! Go the clean way, Otherwise you spend much time searching a bug, you probaly will not find easily.

Answer (score 4):

I am not satisified with the other answers:
You should NOT check for null in compareTo.
It is requested that it throws a NullPointerException, otheriwse you will mess up your Trees and have difficulties finding why your TreeMap does not work.

A very recommendable method:

```
 public int compareTo(Tok other) { 
    int thisRang = this.rang; 
    int otherRang = other.rang; 
    return (thisRang < otherRang ? -1 : (thisRang == otherRang ? 0 : 1)); 
  } 
  public int compareTo(Object other) { 
    return compareTo((Tok)other); 
  }
```

Further to make it perfect class Tok should be final! (Otherwise you could have problems
 when you subclass from Tok. (Sun made that Error in Class Date)

```
final class Tok {
    int rang;
}
```

Dealing with compare and equals is not always easy, consider using instead of Trees (TreeMap) a HashMap, then you dont have to implement compareTo.
You should implement hashCode, where you simply return this.rang.

Finally its is highly recomended, but not mandatory to implement equals()

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
return obj instanceof Tok
    && this.rang() == ((Tok) obj).rang;
}
```

Comment: putting array of Tok objects in to Arrays.sort(tok[]) still yields an exception.

Comment: Yes which Exception? A Nullpointer? This is good! You should not have a Null Object in your Tok[]. Make sure to not add null objectr to your Tok[]

Comment: But thats a problem i know i can shorten my Tok[] not to contain any null indexes however this means i need to create another array count the number of non null indexes then copy this array in to a temporary array and sort that one. Its just to complex i simply want to put all the null elements at the bigest and put them at the end.

Comment: No, no you could create a copy of that array without null elements, or you will later search your bug for 3 or more days, and end up saying java sort, TreeMap, hashMap has a bug. (Like working colleagues told once ;-))

Comment: @AlexWien you seem to be really stuck on the OP using some type of self-sorting collection, but this is clearly not the use case.

Comment: I think it's fine to check for null in compareTo as long as you throw the appropriate Exception. The `obj` may come from a data source out of your control, or you may be providing a utility for objects outside your control.

Comment: @matt and emmerich: then  the compareTo must be an own Comparator class, not part of Tok. And should be named "InsaneTokComparator"

Comment: @emmerich ...or input should be wrapped to take control of the nulls.

Answer (score 1):

Comparing two objects can be as null-safe as any other method, the catch here is that a normal method has two parameters but `compareTo` receives one and the other one is the object itself.

`this` can NEVER be null, that would mean you're executing code in a `null` object (no instance). In this case a `NullPointerException` is going to be thrown right at the invocation of `compareTo`, making impossible the execution of its code.

There are as many approaches as objects, because a comparation can be based in the fields of a class that CAN be null (intended caps to exclude primitive types). So, long story short, your null checks should cover the object you receive as a parameter in `compareTo` and the used fields. In addition, if you have an external instance that holds some logic (i.e. an utilities class) you should check if that instance is also null.

As a side note, whatever you return if any involved object is `null` must be consistent and documented (you can return -1 or 1, to place nulls at the beginning or at the end). Just avoid returning 0 (that would be the same case as if `equals` returned `true` for a `null` object.

Answer (score 1):

Strange as it may seem but it is not safe. Try to add your Tok to TreeSet or TreeMap (as a key) and you will get a NullPointerException. The problem is that TreeSet imlementation is based on TreeMap. When you will try to add(null) underlying map will try to put your null which will result in NPE

Comment: Who says the OP is using a `TreeSet` or `TreeMap`?

Comment: @matt The OP said in one of his comments , he uses sort() which uses compateTo() .

Comment: @AlexWien ...which specifically implies the OP is _not_ using a `TreeSet` or `TreeMap`.

Comment: The point is that he uses compareTo in a way that violates the compareTo() contract of java.

Answer (score 1):

The author is insisting that he does not want to remove null values from his
Tok[].
Here is a soultion that allows to sort with NULL values, and is not violating java contracts

To avoid that, you create a compareTo inside class Tok that violates the compareTo contract,
you create an explicit NullSafeComparator:

```
 /**
 * This comparator accepts null objects,
 * sorts ascending, null values are after non null values.
 */
public static final class NullSafeComparator implements Comparator<Tok> {
    public int compare(Tok o1, Tok o2) {
        int r1 = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int r2 = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        if (o1 != null) {
            r1 = o1.rang;
        }
        if (o2 != null) {
            r2 = o2.rang;
        }
        return (r1 < r2 ? -1 : (r1 == r2 ? 0 : 1));
    }
}
```

simplified class Tok (remove the static keyword its is used to define that all inside one unit test class):

```
public static class Tok {
    int rang;
    public Tok(int rang) {
        this.rang = rang;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return Integer.toString(rang);
    }
}
```

Finally a unit test to show:

```
public void testSort() {

    Tok[] toks = new Tok[5];
    toks[0] = new Tok(3);
    toks[1] = new Tok(1);
    toks[2] = null;
    toks[3] = null;
    toks[4] = new Tok(2);



    Arrays.sort(toks, new NullSafeComparator());



    for (Tok tok: toks) {
        System.out.println(tok);
    }
    assertEquals(1, toks[0]);
    assertNull(toks[4]);
}
```

Which will give the following desired result:

```
1
2
3
null
null
```

Comment: Chill out. `Comparator`s _are_ allowed to be null-safe; [the JavaDoc explicitly says so](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html): _"Unlike `Comparable`, a comparator may optionally permit comparison of null arguments, while maintaining the requirements for an equivalence relation."_

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html):

```
Note that null is not an instance of any class, and e.compareTo(null) should
throw a NullPointerException even though e.equals(null) returns false.
```

So if you implement a null-safe method, its behaviour will be unexpected (aka inconsitent with the documentation and propably with the rest of the API).